$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\ln(x^2 + \cos \frac{\pi x}{2})}{\sqrt{x} - 1}$ using only identical transformations and special limits.
Well, the subject.
I am struggling to do something with $\ln$.
I figured out that I can transmute
$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\ln(x^2 + \cos \frac{\pi  x}{2})}{\sqrt{x} - 1} = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\ln(x^2 + \cos \frac{\pi  x}{2}) \cdot (\sqrt{x} + 1)}{x - 1} = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\ln((x^2 + \cos \frac{\pi  x}{2})^2)}{x - 1}$$
but can't do much since then.
I know it is easily solvable with L'Hôpital's rule, but it is required to solve this limit without advanced techniques.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. What are equal transitions?

@J.G. trigonometric equations, logarithm properties e.t.c. Another term is identical transformations.

@B.Pleshakov can you use the definition of derivative?

@SineoftheTime don't think so.

I guess I solved it.
The main idea is
$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\ln(1 + (x^2 - 1) + \cos \frac{\pi x}{2})}{x - 1} \cdot \frac{(x+1) + \frac{\cos\frac{\pi x}{2}}{x-1}}{(x+1) + \frac{\cos\frac{\pi x}{2}}{x-1}}$$
and then use $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1 + x)}{x} = 1$$
Everything else is a bit technical.

Start using $x=t+1$ and using basic trigonometry
$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\log(x^2 + \cos \frac{\pi  x}{2})}{\sqrt{x} - 1}=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\log((1+t)^2 - \sin \frac{\pi  t}{2})}{\sqrt{1+t} - 1}$$
$$(1+t)^2 - \sin \frac{\pi  t}{2}\sim 1+\left(2-\frac{\pi }{2}\right) t$$
$$\log((1+t)^2 - \sin \frac{\pi  t}{2})\sim \left(2-\frac{\pi }{2}\right) t$$ Now, use the binomial theorem for the denominator and you obtain the solution at the price of two basic equivalents.

As $x\to1$, since $y:=x^2+\cos\frac{\pi x}2-1\to0$, we have
$$\ln\left(x^2+\cos\frac{\pi x}2\right)=\ln(1+y)\sim y
$$
(where the notation $a\sim b$ means $\frac ab\to1$),
$$\frac{x^2-1}{\sqrt x-1}=\sqrt x^3+\sqrt x^2+\sqrt x+1\to4,$$
and since $t:=\sqrt x-1\to0$,
$$\cos\frac{\pi x}2=-\sin\frac{\pi(2t+t^2)}2\sim-\frac{\pi(2t+t^2)}2\sim-\pi t.$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\ln\left(x^2+\cos\frac{\pi x}2\right)}{\sqrt x-1}=4-\pi.$$
